# How to decrease plot size in streamlit?

Tags: plot, streamlit

I set my web app in streamlit to Wide Mode. As a result, the plotted graph fills the entire page, making it very large. Is there any way to plot it as if it were out of Wide Mode, or any way to decrease it? I would like it to be in a size that looks good on both the computer and mobile.

```
            fig1 = plt.figure()
            plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
            plt.axhline(0, linewidth=0.3, color='white')
            plt.plot(1.477*r, v(u, l), color="white")
            plt.plot([1.477/umin,1.477/umax],[vmin,vmax],'bo', color="gold")
            plt.xlabel("r [km]")
            plt.axis([0, 1.477*rmax, -0.5, vlim + 0.1])
            ax = plt.gca()
            ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('white')
            ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')
            ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
            ax.spines['top'].set_color('white') 
            ax.spines['right'].set_color('white')
            ax.spines['left'].set_color('white')
            ax.xaxis.label.set_color('white')
            ax.yaxis.label.set_color('white')
            fig1.patch.set_facecolor('#0E1117')
            ax.set_facecolor("black")
            plt.show()
            st.pyplot(fig1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We are not allowed to control the width of the figure in streamlit.
Although there is a work around:
Step 1: plot a fig while passing `plt.subplot(figsize=(width,height))` argument.
Step 2: Save the fig `fig1.savefig("figure_name.png")`
Step 3: Show the image using [st.image](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/media/st.image)

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('figure_name.png')
st.image(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a minimal example based on a **matplotlib** tutorial to vary the values of the width and height parameters in `figsize` using **sliders** from the [`Cannot change matplotlib figure size`](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/cannot-change-matplotlib-figure-size/10295/2)

```
import streamlit as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cat = ["bored", "happy", "bored", "bored", "happy", "bored"]
dog = ["happy", "happy", "happy", "happy", "bored", "bored"]
activity = ["combing", "drinking", "feeding", "napping", "playing", "washing"]

width = st.sidebar.slider("plot width", 1, 25, 3)
height = st.sidebar.slider("plot height", 1, 25, 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height))
ax.plot(activity, dog, label="dog")
ax.plot(activity, cat, label="cat")
ax.legend()

st.pyplot(fig)
```

or use **[st.columns](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.columns)**

To Insert containers laid out as side-by-side columns. Inserts a number of multi-element containers laid out side-by-side and returns a list of container objects.

[Examples](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.columns)